# How to get a previous version of a table that is before updating the table in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

In Bigquery we use this part of code
FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 6 HOUR).
What is it in postgres?

Comment: PostgreSQL currently doesn't have a "time-travel" facility - there are a couple of extensions that can do some of this functionality, but you'll have to install them before you can make use of them

Answer (score 1):

Per official [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/6.3/c0503.htm), 'As of Postgres v6.2, time travel is no longer supported...New features such as triggers allow one to mimic the behavior of time travel when desired...'